# Too much space in Joomla article and blog

Tags: php, css, joomla

I have a problem with layout of articles page. The problem is that there is too much space after Tilte H1 "Written by" - element and article itself. You can see it here:
http://watersite.loomhost.com/index.php/en/news-eng/40-computer-programmer-cracks

I have managed to get the space between those elements on "blog" page (http://watersite.loomhost.com/index.php/en/news-eng) by adding this code to template.css in my template folder:

```
.blog .items-leading h2 {
   color:#04599a;
   font-size:180%;
   margin-bottom:-15px;
   }
```

but I dont think -15px is correct and there is also some better coded solution for this?

So Im searching for better solution of "margin-bottom" and getting less space between elements on article page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 9 of bootstrap.min.css reads line-height:40px for h2. Plus there is the .page-header element, you might want to look into this, too... just try the "inspect element" tool of Firefox and play around a little ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use pull-right on the div around the toggle.  Also you have a couple of empty divs above the image.